# Twitter / Facebook Sharing in Emails

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, html-email

I have an email that get sent out to users, which needs to have a share to facebook or twitter button.

I know there are URL's which can open the share dialogs etc, but the problem is i need to track the number of shares for the item being shared (just a count).

I know there are things like the Twitter Count API, but it's unofficial, private and not supposed to be used, so i don't want to use that and then have it turned off and left with no data to work with.

The only thing i can think of, is have the email link to my website, which contains JS which opens up the Twitter/Facebook dialog, posts it then in the callback tracks the information back to my server.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the link to an 'essentially' blank webpage, and use a typical Google Analytics tracking parameter on the link to record the count.  Then, create an auto redirect form on the 'blank' webpage so when people click the link, it goes to the page, which then automatically redirects to the share link.

It's a roundabout way of achieving what you want but is one way..